# how to invoke another function when sprites collide in pygame

Tags: python, sprite, pygame

I have the following bit of code which I'm using to delete all of the sprites in the `apple_list` when they collide with the `snake` sprite.  What I would like to know is what is the best way to make something happen when the `snake` sprite collides with a sprite from `apple_list`.  For example, if I wanted to play a sound every time this happens, what's the simplest way to do that?

```
hitApples = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(snake, apple_list, True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no callback manageemnt during sprite collision in pygame.

In your case, you should use something like this :

```
hitApples = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(snake, apple_list, True)
if hitApples:
    callback()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can assign a destructor method to the apple sprites that plays sounds when the sprite is killed:

```
class apple(object):

    ...

    def __del__(self):
        play_sound("fing.ogg")
```

Comment: great idea! wouldnt have thought of that... :D